# C - goto a label that located in an external file

Tags: c, label, extern

Say I got 2 C source files `A.c`, `B.c`.

`A.c` contains a label, that I want to just to from the module `B.c`.

`A.c` contains only 1 function:

```
int f() {
   // some commands
   aLabel:
   // some more commands
   return 1;
}
```

`B.c` also contains only 1 function:

```
extern aLabel;

int g() {
  // do some stuff
  goto aLabel;
}
```

Obviously these 2 files are linked together to a final .exe file.

How do I jump to an external label?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest using functions instead. Make both `f()` and `g()` call some other function at the point where they share code, i.e. from where your label is.

Comment: If you have code that two or more functions need to use, it's a very good fit to break out that code into a separate function.

Comment: **Do not even think abot it!** This is the road to spaghetti code hell. (disclaimer: I do not mean `goto` per se)

Answer (score 5):

`goto` is always local to a function, you cannot jump between functions using `goto`. To do non-local jumps take a look a `setjmp` / `longjmp` C functions.